# Image gets distorted along the edges after using imagerotate function

Tags: php, image, image-rotation, distortion

I am using `imagerotate()` function to rotate the images according to the orientation.

The following image is rotated via `$realignedImage=imagerotate($temp,-90,0);`

[image: Image with EXIF orientation 6]

This is the result of the rotation

[image]

Comment: Maybe it doesn't handle negative angles, try 270..

Comment: Comment above works fine. Alternatively, allocate a white for uncovered pixels with `imagerotate($source, $degrees,imageColorAllocate($source,255,255,255));`